# Default isolation level in Spring Framework

Tags: database, spring, isolation-level

I have a method in *service layer* which does the update functionality to database.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void update(final Object obj){
    // some code here
}
```

Now I want to know what is the isolation level for this method set by Spring framework?

I am a newbie to Spring, just wanted to make myself comfortable with *transactions*.

Please share some best practice and ways to set *isolation level* to avoid deadlocks and thus preventing same user trying to update his record from different browsers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the [docs (`Isolation.DEFAULT`)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Isolation.html#DEFAULT), it uses

> Use the default isolation level of the underlying datastore.

As you are using the `@Transactional` annotation, I would set the isolation level there, e.g.:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
```

Comment: That's correct, but be sure you really need REQUIRES_NEW and SERIALIZABLE. These are usually only needed for something like managing your own sequences. The defaults should be fine for an update.

Comment: @beny23, so if i am right my application will use the default isolation level set by oracle database. Correct ?

Comment: It is READ COMMITTED.  See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-nov/o65asktom-082389.html.